# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory when run in Flex App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, apache-beam

I try to run dataflow pipeline which use a python files that integrated with pickle file below:

dataflow.py

```
    from stopwords import StopWords
    stopwords = StopWords()
    ...
    data = (pipeline | 'read' >> ReadFromText (gs://some/inputData.txt)      
| 'stopwords' >> beam.Map(lambda x:{'id':x['id'],'text': stopwords.validate(x['text'])}))
```

stopwords.py

```
class StopWords:
def __init__ (self):

module_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
self.words = pickle.load(open(os.path.join(module_dir, 'model/sw.p'), "rb"))
```

How ever, I found an error:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow/model/sw.p'

I try to debug `self.words` and it run smoothly. however, it countered a problem when I run it in google cloud dataflow job.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Your `StopWords` class is attempting to load the model (`sw.p`) from the same directory as the `stopwords.py` file, but it seems like the models hasn't gotten deployed along with your code.

Perhaps try putting the `sw.p` file you have locally into a Google Cloud Storage bucket and loading it from there instead?